# telerik expression editor - change return type

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, telerik

I am using Telerik Expression Editor control which uses Finances object which has nullable double fields (values): Debit (10), DebitYTD (100), Credit (20) and CreditYTD (200). In the formula, I want to do something like: Debit - Credit + DebitYTD - CreditYTD and this works fine and returns `LinqExpression<Func<Finances, double?>>` type. The problem is when I try to do something like 0.045 * (Debit) which returns a `LinqExpression<Func<Finances, decimal>>` type. How do I handle two different return types? Can I make expression control to always return `LinqExpression<Func<Finances, double?>>` type?

Answer (score 1):

May this help or do you need to know the exact type?

```
dynamic dynamicExpression = expressionEditor.Expression;
dynamic compiledExpression = dynamicExpression.Compile();
object executionResult = compiledExpression(myInstance);
```

Taken from [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/expression-editor/exposing-result-preview-from-expression-editor.aspx)